# How to save object to another table Springboot

Tags: java, jquery, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to select random employee as employee of the month. It works fine. But I want to save that selected employee to another table which name is EmployeeOfMonth. How can I do this, do I need to use query ? Do I need another repository ? What should be the approach to do this here?

EmployeeRepository :

```
 EmployeeDTO selectEmployee(Employee employee);
```

EmployeeService:

```
 EmployeeDTO selectEmployee(Employee employee);
```

EmployeeServiceImp:

```
 @Override
    public EmployeeDTO selectEmployee(Employee employee) {
        List<Employee> all = employeeRepository.findAll();
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        Employee random = all.get(randomizer.nextInt(all.size()));

            return EmployeeMapper.toDto(random);
        }
```

Controller :

```
@GetMapping(path="/month")
    public EmployeeDTO selectEmployee(Employee employee){
        return employeeService.selectEmployee(employee);
    }
```

Comment: Don't do it. Save the key of the employee to another table, not the whole record.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create another Entity or Table with name EmployeeOfMonths Add attrs like employee id and month. Once you select your employee populate this entity and then save.
So we are not duplicating employee data instead we are referencing it to employee table. To get more details about the employee of the month you can query employee table with employee id from EmployeeofMonths table.

```
@Entity
public class EmployeeOfMonths{
   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;
   private employeeId;
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date created_at;
}
```

### EDIT

I think one employee can become many times Employee of month.
In that case it will be one to many.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EmployeeOfMonths> employeeOfMonths;
```

And for employeemonths.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id", referncedColumnName="employeeId")
private Employee employee;
```

Comment: Thanks you man . But I'm stuck with EmployeeServiceImpemantion part.  I can't save it to employeeOfMonths table. Should I create another repository for employeeOfMotnhs ? Can u help me with that part ?

Comment: Yeah you should create another JpaRepository for this new entity/table and autowire it in your service and call saveAndFlush with the details.

Comment: This saveAndFlush gives error : Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound      @Override
    public EmployeeDTO selectEmployee(Employee employee) {
        List<Employee> all = employeeRepository.findAll();
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        Employee random = all.get(randomizer.nextInt(all.size()));
        Employee save = employeeOfMonthsRepository.saveAndFlush(random);




            return EmployeeMapper.toDto(random);
        }